# How to write a fixed point function in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, fixed-point-iteration

I have a function with the following signature:

```
simCon :: [Constraint] -> Maybe [Constraint]
```

I would like to write a method which, incase simCon returns `Just [Constraint]`, I want to feed them back into simCon and rerun the method, and to keep doing this until the input is the same as the output.

In case of Nothing, I would want to terminate the algorithm.

I have something that would work if both the input and output are the same type

```
fixed :: Eq a => (a -> a) -> a -> a
fixed f a 
  | a == a' = a
  | otherwise = fixed f a'
  where a' = f a
```

But this isn't going to work because I return a Maybe now. Can someone suggest a way to write a similar function but for a return type of Maybe?

Comment: You can unwrap this with pattern matching.

Comment: `fixed (>>= simCon)`?

Comment: where do you put the argument tho?

Comment: @Lana Right after, as with any function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can make use of the bind function here:

```
import Data.Bool(bool)
import Control.Monad(liftM2)

fixedM :: (Eq a, Monad m) => (a -> m a) -> a -> m a
fixedM f = go
    where go x = f x >>= (liftM2 bool go pure <*> (x ==))
```

A more verbose implementation is:

```
fixedM :: (Eq a, Monad m) => (a -> m a) -> a -> m a
fixedM f x = do
    x' <- f x
    if x == x'
        then pure x'
        else fixedM f x'
```

We thus first calculate `x'` with `f x`. In case `f x` return `Just x'`, then we continue. In case `f x` return `Nothing`, the `fixedM` will return `Nothing` as well. We then compare `x` with `x'`. In case the two are equal, we return `pure x'`, otherwise we recurse on `fixedM f x'`.

Alternatively, we can make use of *pattern matching*, although this is basically making the bind operator explicit (and only working for a `Maybe`):

```
import Control.Monad(ap)

fixedM :: Eq a => (a -> Maybe a) -> a -> Maybe a
fixedM f = ap go f
    where go x (Just x') | x == x' = go x' (f x')
                         | otherwise = Just x'
          go _ _ = Nothing
```

we can make it more compact by using *pattern guards*:

```
fixedM :: Eq a => (a -> Maybe a) -> a -> Maybe a
fixedM f = go
    where go x | Just x' <- f x = bool (go x) (Just x) (x == x')
               | otherwise = Nothing
```

Comment: Nice use of monads, but I don't see any pattern matching?

Comment: for some reason, the first function seems to loop infinitely

Comment: @Lana: yes, I swapped `go` and `pure`.

Comment: @Bergi: yes, I changed my mind while writing the answer :).

Comment: Thanks very much!